# Prove $\neg \exists (P(x) \wedge \neg Q(x)) \vdash \forall x (\neg P(x) \vee Q(x))$

Tags: logic, solution-verification

[image]

For this question, I am provided with Line 1 and Line 16 (and Line 1's justification Premise).

I am supposed to fill in all other justifications and the lines.

I was able to use the Proof Machine to verify all the lines I entered, but am stuck on Line 12. I can't figure out how to get $\neg P(n)$ so that I can use it in the $\vee$-intro in Line 13.

Comment: Not very clear... You have derived $Pn$ in 7) and $\lnot Qn$ in 11); if so, derive $Pn \land \lnot Qn$ and then $\exists x (Px \land \lnot Qx)$ contradicting 1). Thus, you can use it to discharge 3) by DN and conclude with 16)

Comment: I know this is not the kind of formal deduction you want, but the intuition may help: $\neg\exists xF(x)$ is equivalent to $\forall x\neg F(x)$, and after this you can use De Morgan law to deduce the desired result.